# Alert on document download

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Hi: We have requirement to setup alert on a document library (alert to defined person); immediately a document is view or downloaded from that library.

Pls adivse if anyone have any idea/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bouncing some ideas around:

Create a custom web part to display the list of documents, where the link would either do some client JavaScript or take you to a page that had some rewrite behaviour as well as sending the alert.

Another option would be to create an HttpModule that intercepted the request. This is lower-level and higher overhead, but would avoid needing to make complex content changes.

Finally, you could have something driven off the logging database, but that might not satisfy your requirement of "immediately".